# How to handle uploaded files in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Google appengine's webapp2 has a very cryptic [documentation regarding the handling of uploaded files](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html#files).

```
Uploaded files are available as cgi.FieldStorage (see the cgi module) instances directly in request.POST.
```

I have a form which makes a POST request of JSON files which I want to store in an NDB.JsonProperty.

Can anyone offer a short example of how do I read the file from the request object?

Comment: Is the POST encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846333/how-does-cgi-fieldstorage-store-files

Comment: Martijn: I am using multipart/form-data, should I be using the other type?

Comment: Paul: question 6846333 did not solve my problem, I am still getting a misterious exception: "lower". I Wish there was a debug toolbar for appengine...

Comment: The debug tool is called the SDK or you use Eclipse pydev, chrome tools ...... You can connect the SDK to the outside world.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form, and then get file content by using in your handler:

```
raw_file = self.request.get('field_name')
```

Then, pass raw_file as input to your model's property.

Answer (score 5):

Google's document just sucks. I've spent about two hours experimenting with webapp2's request object and finally figures out a way to do this.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/30969728/2310396.

The basic code snippets is here:

```
class UploadHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        attachments = self.request.POST.getall('attachments')

        _attachments = [{'content': f.file.read(),
                         'filename': f.filename} for f in attachments]
```

We use `self.request.POST.getall('attachments')` instead of `self.request.POST.get('attachments')`, since they may be multiple `input` field in HTML forms with the same name, so if you just use `self.request.POST.get('attachments')`, you'll only get one of them.

Comment: Note that this solution assumes that you have a form field called `attachments` in your form.  It's not a magic webapp2 keyword or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the solution described in [How does cgi.FieldStorage store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846333/how-does-cgi-fieldstorage-store-files), I used enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form, and

in the handler method for the post I accessed the files via:

```
file_content = self.request.POST.multi['myfieldname'].file.read()
```

it worked!

Comment: I had to define the JsonProperty values as compressed in the Model, otherwise I would get an error of put being too large...