# Using a form to upload a file to the Google App Engine using a static URL

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I am using CrashRpt C++ to upload crash reports from a piece of software I wrote. Crashrpt uploads the data from the crash report to a URL that is set when the program load, in the same way a browser would using a web form.

The CrashRpt send data like this HTML

```
<html>
<form action="THE_WEBSITE" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Application name:<input type="text" name="appname">
Application version:<input type="text" name="appversion">
Email from:<input type="text" name="emailfrom">
Email subject:<input type="text" name="emailsubject">
Crash GUID:<input type="text" name="crashguid">
MD5:<input type="text" name="md5">
Attach ZIP file:<input type="file" name="crashrpt">
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

The only web service we have is the Google App Engine. Is there any way we can actually upload a file using a form to a static address and not the blobstore that requires a dynamic one.

I assume NO.

Comment: Yes, you can use: cgi.FieldStorage. Example use in your handler: file_data = self.request.get("file")

Comment: Can someone confirm that this will work, cause it really doesn't appear to be there when I use self.request.get("file") or self.request.get("crashrpt")

Comment: See my answer code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084667/google-appengine-python-web-upload-file-and-read-the-content

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trivial, self-contained example of how to upload (small -- less than 1 MB!) files to a static url with GAE (with this example, use text files only, since that's how I display them):

```
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class UserFile(ndb.Model):
  filename = ndb.StringProperty()
  filedata = ndb.BlobProperty()


class UploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="/upload_file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">')
        self.response.out.write(
        '''Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form></body></html>''')


class UploadHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        thefile = self.request.POST.get('file')

        filename = thefile.filename
        userfile = UserFile(
          id=filename, filename=filename,
          filedata=thefile.value)
        userfile.put()

        self.redirect('/view_file/%s' % filename)


class ViewHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, fileid):
        k = ndb.Key(UserFile, fileid)
        userfile = k.get()

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(userfile.filedata)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', UploadFormHandler),
                               ('/upload_file', UploadHandler),
                               ('/view_file/([^/]+)?', ViewHandler),
                              ], debug=True)
```