# Uploading Files in webapp2/GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, webapp2

I need to upload and process a CSV file from a form in a Google App Engine application based on Webapp2 (Python) I understand I could use blobstore to temporary store the file but I am curious to know if there is a way to process the file without having to store it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of uploaded files is in `self.request.POST` in your handler, so you can get that content (assuming e.g the field for the uploaded file is named `'foo'`) with e.g

```
content = self.request.POST.multi['foo'].file.read()
```

So now you have the content as a string -- process it as you wish.  This does of course assume the thing **will** fit in memory (no multi-megabyte uploads!-)...

Answer (score 4):

If you need to upload a file via webapp2 with an HTML form, the first thing you need to do is change HTML form `enctype` attribute to `multipart/form-data`, so the code snippet seems like:

```
<form action="/emails" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input multiple id="file" name="attachments" type="file">
</form>
```

In python code, you can read the file directly via `request.POST`, here's a sample code snippet:

```
class UploadHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        attachments = self.request.POST.getall('attachments')

        _attachments = [{'content': f.file.read(),
                         'filename': f.filename} for f in attachments]
```