# Google datastore, upload a file to datastore and download it later

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working with the guestbook example. I added a button type="file" for choosing a file, but I can't seem to be able to upload that to the datastore. Here is what code I have for the button:

```
self.response.out.write("""
    <form action="/sign?%s" method="post">
        <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
        <div>Select a file to upload:<input name="content" type="file" value="file"></div>
        <div><br><input type="submit" value="Upload a File"></div>
    </form>
    <form method="get" download="file">
        <button type="submit">Download</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <form>Name: <input value="%s" name="gae_name">
    <input type="submit" value="switch"></form>
    </body>
    </html>""" % (urllib.urlencode({'gae_name': gae_name}),
                          cgi.escape(gae_name)))
```

I would like if the "Upload a File" button, uploaded it to the datastore like the textarea does. But i can't seem to be able to do that, or find any sample code anywhere.

Comment: You need a `multipart/form-data` form, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973109/uploading-files-in-webapp2-gae/30969728#30969728)

Comment: also datastore is likely not what you want. see cloud storage.

Comment: I got it working. i found a tutorial on youtube on how to upload to datastores, i would appreciate if anyone new any on how to download to your desktop