# How to upload file in python webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am using python webapp2 (Python framework) and google app engine for my project, i want to upload files to my project directory just like move_upload_files in php

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Files in webapp2/GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973109/uploading-files-in-webapp2-gae)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files to the blobstore using webapp2. You first must create the upload url when dispatching to your upload form:

```
        self.render('upload-ui.html', {
             ...
            'form_url': blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_form'),
        })
```

Then in your upload form you use the `form_url`

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ form_url }}" name="formular" class="ui form" accept-charset="UTF-8"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The uploaded files are available from `self.get_uploads` in the post method of your code:

```
for upload in self.get_uploads():
    try:        
        content_type = blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo(upload.key()).content_type

        if 'video' in content_type:
            vid = Video(reference=user)
            vid.content = upload.key()
            vid.title = blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo(upload.key()).filename
            vid.size = blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo(upload.key()).size
            vid.put()

    except Exception, e:
        logging.error('There was an exception:%s' % str(e.message))
        pass
```