# Upload File to AWS S3 from AppEngine using boto3

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, boto3, webapp2

How do I upload file to AWS S3 from my AppEngine application ? Users submitting the file upload form and from AppEngine app, using python I have to upload the file to S3.

```
class FileUpload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        file_data = self.request.POST['file']
```

To upload file object to S3, We have to use `open` method. [Boto Docuement](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj)

```
with open('filename', 'rb') as data:
    s3.upload_fileobj(data, 'mybucket', 'mykey')
```

So here how do I access `file_data` object using `open` method?

Comment: Why not upload to Google's own [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/)?

Comment: Due to the specific architectural design, We have to use S3 instead of GCS.

Comment: according to http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj, you just need to make sure the file_data is bytes type. Then you can use s3.upload_fileobj(file_data, 'mybucket', 'mykey') directly to upload your data.

Comment: @kakashi but how do I replace the `with open` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to omit the `with open` part. According to the [Boto docs you linked to](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj), you need a "file-like object" as the first argument of `s3.upload_fileobj()`. Keeping in mind that self.request.POST['file'] returns a [cgi.FieldStorage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) object, you can get the file-like object like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846333/how-does-cgi-fieldstorage-store-files)):

```
field_storage_obj = self.request.POST.get('file')
file_like_obj = self.request.POST.get('file').file
# or: file_like_obj = field_storage_obj.file
```

The `file_like_obj` is actually an instance of [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), and it has the `.read()` method that is required by Boto of the file-like object.So your final code would look like this:

```
class FileUpload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        file_data = self.request.POST['file'].file
        s3.upload_fileobj(file_data, 'mybucket', 'mykey')
```